# How can I master trigonometry and be able to do quesitons like these

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

Hi, can someone please show me the solution to this? I have no idea where to start. I've never had this concept explained to me. I tried asking a previous question before, but the answers were too complex (except for the one where I just had to sub in..)

Is their a introductory site where I can learn trig identities and stuff like these?

Comment: Practice and practice and you'll see this kind of questions very easy! Do you know the Pythagoras' theorem? Write it!

Comment: Good titles can attract more viewers.

Comment: Check out [Khan|Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For a right triangle, Pythagoras theorem is $$AC^2+BC^2=AB^2$$ You know $AB$ and $BC$; so $AC=???$

For the trigonometric questions, I suppose that you remember that $\cos B=\frac{BC}{AB}$

Just continue along this way. They basically ask you if you remember some definitions.